# How to make userform and active document stand side by side

Tags: vba, ms-word, userform

I am creating a project with MS Word [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) consisting of an active document and a `userform`.

I want the document and userform to stand next to each other. 
The problem is:

- If I set the `modal` userform property = `true`, then the document cannot be edited
- and if the `modal` property = `false`, then the document when zoomed in can be covered under userform. I want both to be visible and active.

**I want both of them to be restricted to each area such as two splitted windows in common cases.**

Is there any VBA code to make it ?!

For all your assistance is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean zoomed, or do you mean if the user changes the window size the document is covered? What does the userform contain that it has to be accessible while the document is being edited?

Answer (score 1):

You can enforce the `Application` or the `UserForm` to change its properties.

You can use

- `Left` for horizontal axis
- `Top` for vertical axis
- `Height` and `Width` are pretty self-explanatory.

If you are familair with `position:absolute;` in [css](/questions/tagged/css), they work exactly the same way

[image]

So If I have my Excel application in full-screen mode.

[image]

> with this code, I upon clicking the button, I can open the `UserForm`
>   while making sure it's not overlapping the excel sheet.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    UserForm1.Show (0)
    Application.WindowState = xlNormal
    Application.Width = 800
    Application.Left = 0
    Application.Top = 0
    UserForm1.Left = 850
End Sub
```

[image]

Obviously you can play around with the properties, depending on your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

May try this with a non-modal `userform` for placing windows like this

[image]

```
Sub test()
Application.ActiveWindow.WindowState = wdWindowStateNormal
Application.ActiveWindow.Top = Application.Top
Application.ActiveWindow.Left = Application.Left
Application.ActiveWindow.Height = Application.UsableHeight
Application.ActiveWindow.Width = Application.UsableWidth / 2
'ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Zoom.Percentage = 50  , may control zoom here



UserForm1.Show
UserForm1.StartUpPosition = 0
UserForm1.ScrollBars = fmScrollBarsBoth
UserForm1.KeepScrollBarsVisible = fmScrollBarsBoth
UserForm1.Top = Application.Top
UserForm1.Left = Application.Left + Application.UsableWidth / 2
UserForm1.ScrollHeight = UserForm1.Height + 10
UserForm1.ScrollWidth = UserForm1.Width + 10
UserForm1.Height = Application.UsableHeight 
UserForm1.Width = Application.UsableWidth / 2
'UserForm1.Zoom = 70                 ' may control zoom
End Sub
```

similarly modifying code may place vertically tiled.

Comment: Edited some typo and added lines regarding scroll of user form.

Comment: Friendly hint:-) Showing a Userform without arguments (`vbModal` or `vbModeless`) as in the code above always defaults to a **modal** Userform and not to a *modeless ("non-modal")* one.